# Data storage for a plugin

Tags: neovim, plugin

I would like to make a plugin for Neovim that does some pretty expensive processing for a text in a file. I would need to keep processed data as well as a hash signature of a file (to avoid
processing of the data without need).

Is there a convention where to keep such information generated by a plugin?

Comment: Probably `tempname()`? Or (\*nix) use a hidden directory like `~/.myplugin` or `/path/to/script/.mycache` or something; `~/.cache/myplugin` also…

Comment: `:help stdpath()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no vim convention for this per se, but there are various operating system conventions.

On neovim, your best bet is probably `stdpath('cache')`.  On linux, this usually resolves to `~/.cache/nvim`.  If needed, you can create a subdir for your plugin like

```
let l:dir = stdpath('cache') . '/myplugin'
if !isdirectory(l:dir)
    call mkdir(l:dir, 'p')
endif
```

In vim, you can emulate stdpath (for linux at least) using

```
let l:stdpath_cache = (empty($XDG_CACHE_HOME)
    \ ? $HOME . '/.cache'
    \ : $XDG_CACHE_HOME) . '/vim'
```

Some plugins write to their install directory but this is not a good practice, as plugins can be installed to system directories to which the user does not have access.

Comment: RE `~/.cache`, agreed. For Windows perhaps `$USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\cache` ... though I'm less sure of that one.  (The dir _does_ exist on my main Win box, FWIW.)

Comment: I see that `stdpath("cache")` on windows points to `$USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Temp\nvim` but using that Windows temp dir is like using `/tmp` on *nix...and not a great choice here, IMO.

Comment: @BLayer generally a bad idea to hard code paths, which is one point of `stdpath()`, I guess the problem then is neovim's choice of paths on windows is inappropriate.

Comment: On Windows `$USERPROFILE\AppData\Local` always exists. It's a standard path meant for, as it says, application data and creating a subdirectory for your particular application is SOP. Though I agree in principle to what you're saying I wouldn't consider this a hard coded path (plus it uses an env var which means it is not hardcoded). (The "cache" part can be dropped if it's not guaranteed to be there...which I haven't googled. Also, I forgot the "{myplugin}" part in my original comment.)

Comment: Not sure but if you mean something else by "hard coded", i.e. any path you create that doesn't come from `stdpath()` I'd argue that what it returns is just as hardcoded. :) Well, except for the platform specific part. That was implied in everything I said, i.e. the plugin would use `if has('win32')` or equivalent when choosing the system-created dir in which to create an app data subdir.

Comment: Re non hard-coding, I am not sure if there is an analog in Windows, but the XDG standard allows the user to configure their cache path (independently from config, data, etc) which neovim's `stdpath()` correctly heeds.  A full solution with includes idiomatic cross-platform handling would be a nice answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that last sentence. I am by no means an expert on Windows dev or admin so I don't know if there's an XDG analogue. If it exists, I'm sure it involves the directory tree I mentioned but what the officially sanctioned ways of accessing it might be I don't know. (Thus my use of comments rather than an answer.)